# how to modify stored dcm files

Tags: dicom, dcm4che

I have the need to mopdify the  information of patient,study,series,instance,and I have done this by putting information to dataset that stored in database.Now my question is that the information stored in database does has been modified but the dcm files stored in pacs can't modified.Is there any way to modify the dcm files at the same time?

Comment: What database is it? The dcm4chee schema? From my experience using dcm4chee this information is entered into the database when the files are sent to dcm4chee. The files are stored separately. I would avoid modifying the data in the dcm4chee database. There are a number of tools in many languages you can use to modify dicom files.

Comment: Yes,I use dcm4chee schema.What you said is quite right.Do you know how dcm4chee modify such files? IS that done via HL7 or some other means?

Comment: dcm4chee doesn't modify the files. The toolkit and library dcm4che (no second e) does allow you to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could be wrong, but I do not believe dcm4chee changes the images when you edit the fields through the web interface.  Instead what it does is it modifies the fields in the data base.  When an image is retrieved from the dcm4chee pacs, it will prepare and send the modified images.  At that point in time it creates a new image header (updated with changes made through the web UI and the changes required because dcm4chee handled the images).  The retriever will then get the modified set of images, dcm4chee will continue to store the original images.

To get the modified images issue a C-STORE request and have dcm4chee send the images to another client or pacs.  That system will receive the modified images.

Comment: I think you are correct, but if you Q/R then the effect should be the same, as you note. Still, if WakingDreamer is grabbing the files from the file system instead of using a standard DICOM transfer, then this information is important. Thanks.

Comment: DCM4chee does not modify the DICOM, but does modify the value of the "attrs" column(pat_attrs, study_attrs,...) that is sent to WEASIS. So if you want to update the patient name, you should update both pat_name and pat_attrs columns :S

Answer (score 2):

If you have DCM4CHEE 2.17.x, then you should be able to edit some information. Go onto the web interface for your installation and look for the Edit [Patient/Study/Series/Instance] Attributes icon (looks like a document with a pencil). If you click on that, you should be able to enter new values for ***some*** of the items.

Most PACS will ignore a storage request if they already have the identical SOP Instance UID value. So, another method to change the data is to use a toolkit to modify the fields you want, and then generate new UID values for the images (and it's a good idea to do the same for the study and series UID values too). This will create duplicate entries, but with different values.

Comment: I also find the web intercace to modify such attributes,and I debuged dcm4chee trying to find out the code that archiving this，but I failed.The program didn't stoped at where I think it should stop.Can you figure out the part that I want?And can you tell me what toolkit do you use?I use java for programing.Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need to do this in code? If you have DCM4CHEE, then just change the values needed and you are done. The next time someone retrieves the data, it should be set to what you've changed.

Comment: I am interested in getting the code generating the dataset in order to reuse it... If anybody can help, he's welcome...